# How to get data out of flutter plugin vCard

Tags: flutter, dart, vcf-vcard

So I'm trying to make an flutter app will display contact information extracted from vcards. But I'm having trouble with how to filter out the data like first name, last name, phone number etc. This is how extracted vcard data looks like

```
I/flutter (11933): BEGIN:VCARD
I/flutter (11933): VERSION:3.0
I/flutter (11933): FN;CHARSET=UTF-8:FirstName MiddleName LastName
I/flutter (11933): N;CHARSET=UTF-8:LastName;FirstName;MiddleName;;
I/flutter (11933): NICKNAME;CHARSET=UTF-8:
I/flutter (11933): BDAY:20201011
I/flutter (11933): TEL;TYPE=WORK,VOICE:Work Phone Number
I/flutter (11933): ORG;CHARSET=UTF-8:ActivSpaces Labs
I/flutter (11933): URL;CHARSET=UTF-8:https://github.com/valerycolong
I/flutter (11933): NOTE;CHARSET=UTF-8:Notes on contact
I/flutter (11933): REV:2020-10-11T15:35:06.168221
I/flutter (11933): END:VCARD
```

Can anyone help me with this. I've tried using [vcard_parser](https://pub.dev/packages/vcard_parser) plugin and its output is also very confusing to me as I'm new in flutter

```
I/flutter (11933): {BEGIN: VCARD, VERSION: 3.0, FN;CHARSET=UTF-8: {name: UTF-8, value: FirstName MiddleName LastName}, N;CHARSET=UTF-8: {name: UTF-8, value: LastName}, NICKNAME;CHARSET=UTF-8: {name: UTF-8, value: }, BDAY: 20201011, TEL;TYPE=WORK,VOICE: {name: WORK,VOICE, value: Work Phone Number}, ORG;CHARSET=UTF-8: {name: UTF-8, value: ActivSpaces Labs}, NOTE;CHARSET=UTF-8: {name: UTF-8, value: Notes on contact}, END: VCARD}
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try [Simple Vcard Parser](https://pub.dev/packages/simple_vcard_parser).**
This is flutter package for extracting data from VCard.

Update your **pubspec.yaml**

```
  dependencies:
  ...
  simple_vcard_parser: ^0.1.3
```

Usage:

```
import 'package:simple_vcard_parser/simple_vcard_parser.dart';
VCard vc = VCard(myVCard);
print(vc.version); 
print(vc.formattedName); 
print(vc.organisation); 
print(vc.title); 
print(vc.email); 
print(vc.typedTelephone); 
print(vc.name);
```